# Python printing beginner

Tags: python, input, printing

I just started with python. My teacher gave me an assignment and I'm stuck on a project where I have to make the numbers of characters appear when someone enters their name for input command *input("what is your name")* I don't think I have been taught this and google is giving me a hard time when trying to look for the command. This might be Childs play to most but can anyone throw me a tip/hint?

Comment: Start with `print(input("what is your name"))` and observe how that prints out the string that the user enters.  Now change it to `print(len(input("what is your name")))`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `print(len(myVariable))` should output the number of characteres that the string has. You should familiarize yourself with python methods.
Here are some resources:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp

Answer (score 0):

Printing the length of a variable is very easy with Python due to the many built-in functions you can perform on strings! In this case, you would use use `len()`. Read about [other helpful string methods in python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/built-in-string-methods-in-python) too in order to get a head start on your class!

```py
inputtedName = input("What is your name? ")
nameLength = len(inputtedName)
print("Your name is " + str(nameLength) + " letters.")
print(f"Your name is {nameLength} letters.")
```

The first print statement uses something called [string concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp) to create a readable sentence using variables. The second uses [f strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) to make using variables in your strings even easier!